# Is it possible to remove the millisecond speed reported by Mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

In the Mocha/Chai javascript testing framework is it possible to remove the millisecond speed reported by Mocha?

I'd like an easier way to compare outputs from different tests, and currently each test line shows a diff since the speed (ms) varies from run to run.

```
test1.js
    description here
      ✔ should do the things (211ms)
```

Comment: Can you give an output example?

Comment: @slideshowp2 just updated to show what i'm talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha use `spec` as its default reporter.The `spec` reporter inherits from `Base` reporter. It use [.epilogue()](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/8421974e8d252e2ef11602d15bed178e4f5f4534/lib/reporters/base.js#L351) method of `Base` for `EVENT_RUN_END` event.

The method will print the milliseconds, the source code:

```js
Base.consoleLog(fmt, stats.passes || 0, milliseconds(stats.duration));
```

You can [create a custom reporter](https://mochajs.org/api/tutorial-custom-reporter.html) for mocha.

`./reporters/tidy.js`:

```js
const Mocha = require('mocha');
const { EVENT_RUN_END, EVENT_TEST_FAIL, EVENT_TEST_PASS } = Mocha.Runner.constants;

class Tidy {
  constructor(runner) {
    const stats = runner.stats;
    runner
      .on(EVENT_TEST_PASS, (test) => {
        console.log(`pass: ${test.fullTitle()}`);
      })
      .on(EVENT_TEST_FAIL, (test, err) => {
        console.log(`fail: ${test.fullTitle()} - error: ${err.message}`);
      })
      .once(EVENT_RUN_END, () => {
        console.log(`end: ${stats.passes}/${stats.passes + stats.failures} ok`);
      });
  }
}

module.exports = Tidy;
```

Use [fullTitle() → {string}](https://mochajs.org/api/suite#fullTitle) to

> Return the full title generated by recursively concatenating the parent's full title.

It will give you `pass: <test suite title>  <test case title>` string.

Example test:

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('description here', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(1 + 1).to.be.equal(2);
  });
  it('should fail', () => {
    expect(1 + 1).to.be.equal(3);
  });
});
```

Output:

```sh
⚡  npx mocha --reporter ./reporters/tidy.js /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/reporters/index.test.js 
pass: description here should pass
fail: description here should fail - error: expected 2 to equal 3
end: 1/2 ok
```

Answer (score 0):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69231640/1166285) is more sophisticated, I've found a much cheaper way to remove the speeds by increasing the `--slow` option to a very large number since the speed only appears for slow tests.